# how to write react class as a plain javascript class?

Tags: ecmascript-6, react-native

I am learning react native.  i want to rewrite the following line using a plain javascript class.

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
```

to

```
export class Dashboard extends React.Component {
```

not sure if i am doing it right.  in the original code, it just exports without giving a class name. can I do the same? or does it hurt if I give a name.

the full source code is [there](https://github.com/iSimar/HackerNews-React-Native/blob/master/App/Views/Dashboard/index.ios.js). the line i try to modify is line 19.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I depends on how you import the component. You are currently using [named export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Using_named_exports) so you need to import it by it's name - `Dashboard`:

```
export class Dashboard extends React.Component {

// and then import by name
import { Dashboard } from './myfile';
// or with require
var Dashboard = require('./myfile').Dashboard;
```

If you use [default export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Using_the_default_export) you can name it however you like:

```
export default class Dashboard extends React.Component {

// and then import
import Dashboard from './myfile';
// or with custom name
import MyComponent from './myfile';
// or with require
var Dashboard = require('./myfile');
```